# Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code ubuntu 20.04

Tags: php, mysql

Tried running systemctl status mysql.service after mysql wont restart got the following log kindly help:

Comment: For such errors we need to see the error log of mysql that usually shows exactly what is wrong and tells you also how to fix it

Comment: " the following log"....I think you forgot to post the actual log data.

Comment: @nbk I am unable to post my log here kindly help me out on how to

Comment: open it i a text editor and add the content to your qiestion, or you have to describe your problem a bit more detailed

Comment: Press the "edit" button of your question and then paste the relevant text from your log